# Android Studio Multi Preview?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio for MAC, version 3.6.3.

[I read that I can use Multi Preview on Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#4.0-multi-preview). In Xcode I could have live preview while coding on how it looks like on multiple devices, but I can only see one device at a time in Android Studio?

I want something like this:
[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56BiI.png)

Comment: It is for AS 4.0. You can update to it on Canary Channel (https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/10/android-studio-40-canary-1-available.html, https://developer.android.com/studio/preview). Or you can use several emulators (they work independently).

Comment: The multi preview feature is listed under studio 4.0 which is yet to be released in stable channel.

Comment: @CoolMind So I need to download this one: https://developer.android.com/studio/preview ? The one that says `DOWNLOAD 4.1 CANARY 9`?

Comment: @Antonio Ok, so if I am new to Android development, I should just wait for the stable release?

Comment: @regke, yes, you can. I didn't try, but know, that some developers tried. Some developers even have several AS installed on one computer. Yes, it is not stable release with bugs.

Comment: But what, there was a video from 2013 about this, and they havent released it yet? Ref: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Hf5P2hjv5k

Comment: seems like it was available back then. And they removed it in some version. Now it is planned to be released with 4.0

Comment: I just installed the .1 CANARY, but there is no option for multiple devices?

Comment: @regke, that is strange. Can you post a screenshot of a top-right angle of the IDE?

Comment: @CoolMind I think I found it: https://ibb.co/DWBsgDh, on the right side it says "Layout Validation", and that is where all the previews are showing :)

Comment: @regke, :) So, they even didn't do what promosed.

Comment: @CoolMind What do you mean?

Comment: @regke, maybe I didn't understand you right. So, that is what you searched for?